# Will Oracle SQL Developer version 19.2 and Oracle APEX version 4.2 support each other when making changes to application?

Tags: version, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

My query in SQL Developer is executing fine, but when I implement in APEX, the application won't even run. So just wondering if Developer version and APEX version are compatible.

Comment: If you are talking about a **query** then what matters is the Oracle **database** version.  If your APEX environment and SQL Developer are linked to the same database then this won't be an issue.  What do you mean exactly by "won't even run"?  Is there an error message?

Comment: Yes, when i make changes in APEX, and click run, it says to contact IT and be descriptive. But when I undo the changes, the application runs fine. 

This is what I am trying to do:
- adding new validation to an existing field. validation statement should be: "if a < 10 or > 57 then return an error"

Answer (score 2):

There is no relationship between SQL Developer and your APEX application, at least as far as the scenario you're describing.

It would help to show your query, show your application not running, i.e. error messages encountered when running the query.

If you wanted, you could test the query in the APEX SQL Workshop.

SQL Developer runs its queries through a jdbc driver as a client application. APEX SQL runs inside the database via stored procedures.

Comment: this is the query I ran in workshop:
begin
if (a < 10) or (a > 57) then
  return '#LABEL# is not between the valid range of 10 and 57.';
end if;
end;

I received an error: In a procedure, RETURN statement cannot contain an expression

How can I modify into a function?

Comment: that's not a query - update your question with the complete PL/SQL block you are calling

Answer (score 1):

Based on a comment you posted: what you executed in Apex' SQL Workshop is an anonymous PL/SQL block.

By the way, what is `a`? You never declared it.

How to transform it to a function? For example:

```
create or replace function f_test (a number) 
  return varchar2 is
begin
  return case when a < 10 or a > 57 then 'Value is not in valid range' 
              else null
         end;
end;
/
```

Call it as e.g. (in function's body)

```
return f_test(:P1_DEPTNO);
```

---

Aha, yet another comment: that is supposed to be a validation. Its type should be "PL/SQL function returning error text":

```
  return case when :P1_DEPTNO < 10 or :P1_DEPTNO > 57 
                   then 'Value is not in valid range' 
              else null
         end;
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am new to this, not sure if this is working properly or not.

**var min := select LV R 
from LV
where id = (select id from tab1 where col2 = 'range')
and desc = 'min'; **

**var max := select LV R 
from LV
where id = (select id from tab1 where col2 = 'range')
and desc = 'max'; **

**begin 
if :P1_range < min or :P1_range > 57 then 'invalid range'
end if;
end; **

the above ^ will be my 2nd validation statement.
i have one validation statement in place that the field must have a value in it. 

Does the query look good?

Comment: How do I highlight the query texts?

Comment: Don't post code as a comment; as you can see, it is unreadable. Edit the original question you posted (there's the EDIT link below it) and add code - properly formatted - in there.

Comment: Further detail to this question also seems to have provided here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60528180/querying-for-2nd-validation-statement-on-an-existing-field-in-apex/60535686#60535686