# Querying for 2nd validation statement on an existing field in APEX

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

```
where id = (select id from tab1 where col2 = 'range') and desc = 'min'; 

var max := select LV R from LV 
where id = (select id from tab1 where col2 = 'range') and desc = 'max';

begin if :P1_range < min or :P1_range > max then 'invalid range' 
end if; 
end;
```

the above ^ will be my 2nd validation statement. i have one validation statement in place that the field must have a value in it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please review [ask]. Following this as a template greatly increases your chance of getting a satisfactory answer. In this case: What is the question? Inclued complete SQL and sample data with expected results - an text not images.

Comment: Please add more context to it. I can't really make out what exactly is the question.

Comment: Also be aware that session state values are stored as strings. Number and date comparisons should have explicit conversiions, to_number(:P1_range)

Comment: Hi Sumaita, are you still having difficulty with this? Did you see Scott's answer?

Answer (score 1):

When using validations, the exact syntax will depend on the Type you've selected. Use the inline help to ensure you match expression format.

[image: Validation example from Page Designer]

Also make sure you explicitly convert and numbers and dates, since sessions state is stored as a string.

If you receive any errors, it's best to describe them here, as they will allow for quicker resolution.

Comment: Thank you, this helped and I was able to resolve this issue.